# Error in saving an ontology with jena

Tags: java, save, runtime-error, jena, ontology

I'm trying to create a new ontology and after some actions save it. It's been created well and I have no problem in dealing with classes and other things but when I try to save it to a local file gives me an error!
My code is:

```
//create a new ontology
SOURCE = "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#";
NS = SOURCE + "#";
ontology = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
ontology.read( SOURCE, "RDF/XML" );
///////some actions
//save the ontology
try {
        File file= new File("Log.owl");
        ontology.write(new FileOutputStream(file));

    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And the error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.BadURIException: Only well-formed absolute URIrefs can be included in RDF/XML output: <d> Code: 57/REQUIRED_COMPONENT_MISSING in SCHEME: A component that is required by the scheme is missing.
at com.hp.hpl.jena.xmloutput.impl.BaseXMLWriter.checkURI(BaseXMLWriter.java:829)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.xmloutput.impl.BaseXMLWriter.xmlnsDecl(BaseXMLWriter.java:348)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.xmloutput.impl.Basic.writeRDFHeader(Basic.java:56)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.xmloutput.impl.Basic.writeBody(Basic.java:39)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.xmloutput.impl.BaseXMLWriter.writeXMLBody(BaseXMLWriter.java:500)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.xmloutput.impl.BaseXMLWriter.write(BaseXMLWriter.java:472)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.xmloutput.impl.BaseXMLWriter.write(BaseXMLWriter.java:458)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.write(ModelCom.java:271)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntModelImpl.write(OntModelImpl.java:2552)
```

I know that the format of "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" is TURTLE but I'd like to have the ontology in RDF/XML and I don't know what to write instead of that link.I tried different links but each time it gave me another error. Should SOURCE be a real link?

Thaks for any reply !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I managed to find the solution! And it was easier than I thought!My problem was in creating the classes. My code was:

```
ontology.createClass(word);
```

I had to write:

```
ontology.createClass(NS+word);
```

A piece of cake!

Comment: Basically, solution to these kind of errors is adding "namespace"; whether its in class or in individual Subject, object, predicate (Resources). Without namespace, it does not allow to write ontology in RDF/XML

Answer (score 1):

Try reading as Turtle - the output will be RDF/XML (but you want to use RDF/XML-ABBREV which is neater.  Internally it is held as triples, not in some concrete syntax as read.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I could run it by using TURTLE but the output is in TURTLE too!

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the ontology using format `"TURTLE"`, not `"RDF/XML"`. You can select a different format when writing, see the [Jena Model javadoc](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html) for the different versions of the `write()` method. Choose one where you can specify the output format (`lang`) and use `"RDF/XML-ABBREV"` as AndyS says.

The exception is because you used a simple string (apparently `"d"`) in a location where only full absolute URIs are allowed (such as `"http://example.com/mydata#d"`). Perhaps in a call to `createResource()`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion cygri.I have no problem with TURTLE and it works perfectly but I want the output in RDF/XML and when I write ontology.write(new FileOutputStream(file), "RDF/XML-ABBREV"); it gives me that error again!Unfortunately I couldn't understand your last question.

Comment: No, the error is exactly in writing on the local file!I've traced it carefully.

Comment: And when I write     ontology.write(new FileOutputStream(file), "TURTLE");    it works well. That is the reason of my confusing!

Comment: No, seriously, the problem is in the “some actions”. You're generating something that cannot be serialized as RDF/XML. Try removing the “some actions” part to save the original as RDF/XML without making any changes. If that works, then the problem must be in the “some actions” part, right?

Comment: Although I removed that part it kept giving me the error!I need my ontology in owl. I'd had some problems with OWL API so I've switched to jena and now OWL API can't read TURTLE and I don't know how to change TURTLE to owl...

Comment: Seriously: I have tested the code snippet that you have given above and IT WORKS, after adding the missing type declarations for the variables and changing the input format to `"TURTLE"`. If you get any errors, then you're running different code from what you showed above. Nobody can help you if you don't show the code that you're actually running.

Comment: Of course when I'd changed RDF/XML to TURTLE it's worked but now I have an output in TURTLE!I want it in RDF/XML.

Comment: I have tested the code snippet that you have given above, and it produces RDF/XML after I made the changes I described. What's wrong with you? I will never again help you with anything.

Comment: Excuse me in case I bothered you. I'm not mad! My code is what I said and if I knew what's wrong I didn't ask others!I don't know what is missing and still I have problem but thanks for your help and kindly suggestions.